# Ionic error when trying to run on android device

Tags: ionic4

When I run the command: `ionic cordova run android`

This error is showing up:

> [ERROR] native-run was not found on your PATH. Please install it globally:

I also tried to run `sudo npm i -g native-run` but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try with yarn global add native-run also try to remove and add again.

Comment: still same error

Comment: This may help you. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2214

Comment: Is this issue got resolved? I am getting the same error in my project.